# Apache Pig : Append two data sets to one

Tags: apache-pig, union

i have two data sets

1st set A

(111)

(222)

(555)

2nd set B

(333)

(444)

(666)

i did 
C = UNION A,B;

after appending two data sets output should be first data set and next second data set

Expected output C is

(111)

(222)

(555)

(333)

(444)

(666)

But my output C is

(333)

(444)

(666)

(111)

(222)

(555)

if i apply union the result is in not order 
it is difficult to me to append them in set order
How can i do this ?
i cant think of any but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try `ORDER`. For that you must include the keys A and B to be able  to sort on them

Comment: thanks for u comment
here i have only one column in both sets A and B
and the output should not be order of rows
it should be in the order of sets
like all the rows of set A should come first and Second set B rows
i could not find any solution for this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra column to each of the files giving the file_number and then do union of the modified data sets, followed by sorting based on the column giving 'file_number'

```
A = LOAD 'A.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (a:int);
B = LOAD 'B.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (b:int);
A_mod = FOREACH A GENERATE a, 1 AS file_number;
B_mod = FOREACH A GENERATE b, 2 AS file_number;
unified_mod = UNION A_mod, B_mod;
output = SORT unified_mod BY file_number;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've try the classic union and for me the data stay in order.

But let's try to force-it if it doesn't :)

well as I said in the previous comment it's not efficient but it makes the job.

```
--In order to determine nbA you can run the following cmd in the shell : wc -l A.txt
%default nbA 3

A = LOAD 'A.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (a:int);
B = LOAD 'B.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (b:int);

A = RANK A;
B = RANK B;

--DESCRIBE B; 
B = FOREACH B GENERATE rank_B + $nbA, $1;

C= UNION B,A;
C= ORDER C BY $0;
C= FOREACH C GENERATE $1; --If you want to drop the first column
DUMP C;
```

Output :

```
(111)
(222)
(555)
(333)
(444)
(666)
```

Where :

A.txt

```
111
222
555
```

And B.txt:

```
333
444
666
```